# IMAP installed but not working?

Tags: php, linux, apache, imap

I have installed PHP IMAP with `yum` on CentOS, but it is not working. It is enabled, also listed when I execute `php -m`, but I still get the PHP error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open()`

I did restart apache, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `php -m` you run the PHP CLI, Apache uses the SAPI module. It's possible they use different `php.ini` and the Apache module does not load the `imap` extension. Write `<?php phpinfo();` in a page and check its output in browser to find out what `php.ini` it loads (maybe it doesn't load any) and if the `imap` module is loaded.

Comment: They're using the same php.ini - any other ideas?

Comment: How do I test it? I also notice that in `phpinfo()` it is not not including the additional .ini files. imap.ini is located in the /etc/php.d/ folder, and it is including from there. I dont understand why it is not loading it. Also having same issue when trying to install php gd.

Comment: Write a small script that only calls `imap_open()` with the correct connection parameters and dumps its result (with `print_r()` or `var_dump()`). Run the script from the command line: `$ php script.php` and check the output.